# Test Case Error and need to create session mock

Tags: spring, struts2, junit4

I would like to ask some testing problems of my web application. I used the following test case

```
      public class LoginActionTestCase extends StrutsSpringTestCase {
          @Test
          public void testInputs() throws IOException {
              SC001LoginAction action = new SC001LoginAction();
              SC001LoginForm form = new SC001LoginForm();
              form.setUserId("U001");
              form.setPassword("12345678");
              action.setLoginActionForm(form);
              assertTrue(action.validateInput());
      }
```

This code is ok when extends `junit.framework.TestCase` but an exception occur when extends `StrutsSpringTestCase`. The exception is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext`.

My web application is integrated by Struts 2.3.14.2, Spring 3.2.3 and JUnit 4.11.And I would like to test session values means I put logged in User object to current session and how could I test this User Object from session using JUnit. If JUnit cannot handle this, please share me some ideas or references.

Comment: You're missing a dependency, just like the error message says.

Comment: It is higly suggested you upgrade to 2.3.16 due to security issues.